# Error when using freemember module

Tags: module, login, freemember, logout

I am using freemember(https://github.com/expressodev/freemember) for login in and registration. I just installed it and I'm logged in as admin. When i try to logout i get this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: require(/home/a7116614/public_html/ee/system/expressionengine/modules/member/mod.member.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: libraries/freemember_lib.php

Line Number: 554


Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/a7116614/public_html/ee/system/expressionengine/modules/member/mod.member.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/a7116614/public_html/ee/system/expressionengine/third_party/freemember/libraries/freemember_lib.php on line 554
```

I used my ftp client to check and navigate to **public_html/ee/system/expressionengine/modules/member/mod.member.php**, but **member/mod.member.php**  does not exist.
Please help me, I am stuck here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using the Core Version of EECMS. The [core version](https://store.ellislab.com/#ee-core) doesn't have the member module.

Comment: yes! I didn't know that :(